# Microsoft VB: Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm currently trying to implement some code into my excel so when a user selects one check box the other check boxes will be unselected. This is the following code I have for it:

```
Sub CheckBox77_Click()
 If CheckBox77.Value = True Then
        CheckBox78.Value = False
 End If
End Sub
Sub CheckBox78_Click()
 If CheckBox78.Value = True Then
        CheckBox77.Value = False
 End If
End Sub
```

When I test this, I get an error that says:

Run-time error '424': Object Required.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `Me.CheckBox77.Value`

Comment: Is the `CheckBox` on a userform or it is an ActiveX control?

Comment: I suggest using Option Buttons, as they already do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @franciscod Me.CheckBox77.Value returned an error saying it was an invalid use of Me.

Comment: @AlexP it is userform

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for the suggestion, I'm leaning towards that as the last resort, since I have like 200 checkboxes already..

Comment: What is the module name where you have these subs?

Comment: @paulbica it says 'Module1'

Comment: This is the problem, your code needs to be in your userform module, which you can reach by double-clicking it in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want to place those methods in **"Module1"**, you should use as follow:

```
If Sheets("sheetname").CheckBox78.Value = True Then
    Sheets("sheetname").CheckBox77.Value = False
End If
```